# Using matlabs save in functions

Tags: matlab, scope, save, workspace

Is it possible to use the Matlab save command inside a function to store workspace variables?

Consider following scenario: I've got a bunch of variables in the Matlab workspace and want all that are beginning with "a" and "b" in a .mat file. Of course this works:

```
save('test.mat','a*','b*')
```

but i want to have a variable filename. The function i wrote:

```
function save_with_name(name)
save(name,'a*','b*')
```

does not work, because save_with_name doesn't see the workspace variables. Is there a solution which i can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to evaluate `save` in the base workspace.

```
function save_with_name(name)
expression = ['save(''', name, ''',''a*'',''b*'')'];
evalin('base',expression);
```

The double-quotes ('') in the expression are necessary to allow the quote character itself (').
Thus the command you're looking for is: [evalin](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html)

Comment: +1. Might want `'caller'` instead of `'base'`; then it would work when called from other functions as well.